# Server's thread communicate with client implementation

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server

I am not sure how to implement a server with threads such that threads communicate with client and at the same time server is able to set new connections. What should I pass to the new thread?

If someone has a snippet of code as a proof of concept it will be very helpful.
My client has to pass a parameter when connects and the thread has to use that parameter, to implements certain operations and return the result to client.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'What should I pass to the new thread?' - the server<>client socket as returned by an accept() call.

Comment: Maybe.  Whatever 'socket descriptor' is returned by your OS.  Usually, it is an int-size fd, or handle, or whatever.